# Change the name position between two differents columns values in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data.frame that shows the correlation between water quality and land use parameters.
In this data.frame you have the columns `xName`, `yName`, `corr`, and `p.value`.
However, in the column `xName`, `yName` was not a separate column just for quality and solo use.

For example, I would like only the water quality data in the `xName` column, and in the `yName` column, only the land use data, since the order would not change the value of `corr` and  `p.value`

Initially, I thought of creating the new columns with `mutate` where it shows whether `xName` and `yName` is land use and water quality, then using `case_when` and `recode` to switch the possibility names.

But I can't move forward, because it returns an error and doesn't change the name.

```
df=read.table(text="xName   yName   corr    p.value classe_tipox2   classe_tipoy2
IQA_mean    soil    0.639727697 0.025073852 water   land
OD_mean veg 0.60989011  0.03029001  water   land
OD_mean grass   -0.576923077    0.042537186 water   land
soil    N_Total_mean    0.604577823 0.037305053 land    water
crop    N_Total_mean    0.695600561 0.012007646 land    water
crop    P_Total_mean    -0.624544589    0.029931227 land    water
DBO_mean    veg 0.797202797 0.003161252 water   land
DBO_mean    city    0.756757445 0.004382975 water   land
DBO_mean    grass   -0.825174825    0.001718596 water   land
veg P_Total_mean    -0.587412587    0.048844858 land    water
P_Total_mean    grass   0.629370629 0.03239475  water   land", sep="", header=TRUE)%>%
   
  #change names positions
    mutate(xName=case_when(
    classe_tipox2=='land' & classe_tipoy2=='water' ~ recode(xName=yName )
  ))
```

I would like `xName` to be renamed to `yName` when `xName` is of type land use.

Comment: `recode` needs some value? Maybe just put `yName` here (`classe_tipox2=='land' & classe_tipoy2=='water' ~ yName`? Why is calling `recode` necessary? BTW, you can use `%in%` for multiple matches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please find below one simple solution using `dplyr` and two `ifelse` statements. Please note that I simplify your conditions in `ifelse` because it seems enough.

**Reprex**

- Code

```r
library(dplyr)

  df %>% 
    mutate(xName2 = ifelse(classe_tipox2 == 'land', yName, xName),
           yName = ifelse(classe_tipoy2 == 'water', xName, yName)) %>% 
    select(-xName) %>% 
    relocate(xName2, .before = yName) %>% 
    rename_with(.cols = 1, ~"xName")
```

- Output

```r
#>           xName yName       corr     p.value classe_tipox2 classe_tipoy2
#> 1      IQA_mean  soil  0.6397277 0.025073852         water          land
#> 2       OD_mean   veg  0.6098901 0.030290010         water          land
#> 3       OD_mean grass -0.5769231 0.042537186         water          land
#> 4  N_Total_mean  soil  0.6045778 0.037305053          land         water
#> 5  N_Total_mean  crop  0.6956006 0.012007646          land         water
#> 6  P_Total_mean  crop -0.6245446 0.029931227          land         water
#> 7      DBO_mean   veg  0.7972028 0.003161252         water          land
#> 8      DBO_mean  city  0.7567574 0.004382975         water          land
#> 9      DBO_mean grass -0.8251748 0.001718596         water          land
#> 10 P_Total_mean   veg -0.5874126 0.048844858          land         water
#> 11 P_Total_mean grass  0.6293706 0.032394750         water          land
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Another option (though a little verbose). First, I put the data into long format, then use `ifelse` statements to "fix" the `xName` and `yName`, then I pivot the data back to wide format.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(c(xName, yName)) %>%
  mutate(
    name = ifelse(
      name == "xName" &
        classe_tipox2 == 'land',
      "yName",
      ifelse(
        name == "yName" &
          classe_tipox2 == 'land',
        "xName",
        name
      )
    )
  ) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value) %>% 
  select(5:6, 1:4) %>% 
  mutate(classe_tipox2 = "water", classe_tipoy2 = "land")
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 11 × 6
   xName        yName   corr p.value classe_tipox2 classe_tipoy2
   <chr>        <chr>  <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>         <chr>        
 1 IQA_mean     soil   0.640 0.0251  water         land         
 2 OD_mean      veg    0.610 0.0303  water         land         
 3 OD_mean      grass -0.577 0.0425  water         land         
 4 N_Total_mean soil   0.605 0.0373  water         land         
 5 N_Total_mean crop   0.696 0.0120  water         land         
 6 P_Total_mean crop  -0.625 0.0299  water         land         
 7 DBO_mean     veg    0.797 0.00316 water         land         
 8 DBO_mean     city   0.757 0.00438 water         land         
 9 DBO_mean     grass -0.825 0.00172 water         land         
10 P_Total_mean veg   -0.587 0.0488  water         land         
11 P_Total_mean grass  0.629 0.0324  water         land
```

Answer (score 2):

A **base R** approach

```
# get the conditional logic
chose <- df$classe_tipox2 == "land"

# then select the columns and bind with the rest of the data
cbind(setNames(data.frame(t(sapply(seq_along(chose), function(x) 
  'if'(chose[x], c(df$yName[x],df$xName[x]), c(df$xName[x],df$yName[x]))))), 
  colnames(df[,1:2])), df[,-c(1,2)])

          xName yName       corr     p.value classe_tipox2 classe_tipoy2
1      IQA_mean  soil  0.6397277 0.025073852         water          land
2       OD_mean   veg  0.6098901 0.030290010         water          land
3       OD_mean grass -0.5769231 0.042537186         water          land
4  N_Total_mean  soil  0.6045778 0.037305053          land         water
5  N_Total_mean  crop  0.6956006 0.012007646          land         water
6  P_Total_mean  crop -0.6245446 0.029931227          land         water
7      DBO_mean   veg  0.7972028 0.003161252         water          land
8      DBO_mean  city  0.7567574 0.004382975         water          land
9      DBO_mean grass -0.8251748 0.001718596         water          land
10 P_Total_mean   veg -0.5874126 0.048844858          land         water
11 P_Total_mean grass  0.6293706 0.032394750         water          land
```